# Closing terminal which are not running commands without a prompt

Tags: command-line, unity, sudo, gnome-terminal, process

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 16.10 (Unity) alongside Windows 10 which was already installed.

I found myself using a terminal a lot, but there is something which kinda bugs me: even if no command is running, if I'm logged in as root (I mean after typing `sudo su` and then my password) when I want to close the terminal it will prompt me with this

[image]

How can I close it without that message popping up? I want it to pop up only if the terminal is executing some command.

Comment: Well it is saying that message because `sudo su` is a process, so I don't know!

Comment: It is executing a command `sudo su` so its supposed to ask before closing the terminal. Don't wan to see it then do `exit` then close terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is running.  **su** is running.  You can verify if you have a clean terminal with everything closed by typing `exit` at the prompt.

If you exit out of `su`, then you can close it without getting the `process running on this terminal`, prompt.

If a process is running, just keep executing `exit` until all the processes are closed.

Comment: Thanks I had no idea it was identifiable as a process